# Put the html tags in the title property of the image tag (Text formatting in the image tag)

Tags: asp.net

```
using (SqlConnection conn = DataAccess.GetConnected())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetImageForSlider", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader sqr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqr.Read())
            {
                string image_path = sqr.GetString(0);
                string description = sqr.GetString(1);
                string action = sqr.GetString(2);
                HtmlImage += "<img src=\"" + image_path + "\" title=\"" + "<h3>" + description + action + "\".</h3><p><br></p><ahref=http://www.giftotravels.com >Thisislink</a>" + "/>";

            }
        }
```

i am trying to as above but this is not working properly
any one can help???

Comment: What are you trying to do????

Comment: What is not working exactly? Put the error.

Comment: I need to format the text
with <h3> , <a> and <span> tag if i write as it is in the aspx page it is working properly but here not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert html tags inside image tag; it becomes invalid format. You want to render html like this.

```
HtmlImage += string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" title=\"/><h3>{1}{2}.</h3>" +
   "<p><br></p><a href='http://www.giftotravels.com'>Thisislink</a>", 
    image_path, description, action);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The title attribute gets rendered as plain text. If you want to do text markup, create an element yourself and let that float above the picture on mouseover.

Comment: can you give me a little example??

Comment: HtmlImage += string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" title=\"<h3>{1}.</h3><span class=price>{2}</span><p><br></p><a href=http://www.giftotravels.com >This is link</a>\"/>",image_path, description, action);

i've done with this

Comment: @user what does that print?